# Interpretation of Tensorboard Images for Object detection

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, object-detection, tensorboard

I am training different models with Tensorflow Object Detection using this github [library](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection).
When I monitor the Tensorboard while training, I see the "**Images**" tab along with "*Scalars*" && "*Time series*" tabs like below.

[image]

I am trying to interpret what is shown under this "**Images**" tab as shown below
[image]

I tried googling about this and didn't manage to find any help specific to this. Any explanations or references are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, TensorBoard is a visualization toolkit, which allows you to visualize almost anything you need to help you interpret your model behavior.

Alongside showing diagrams in scalars or time series, it can give you other things, such as a look at the graphics in your datasets. Often, you might write code in Python to render some images in your dataset prior to training, just for quick look to see if they're loading correctly. You could use TensorBoard for this too and in many cases, preventing you needing to have graphic libraries linked in to your code for the graphic rendering, allowing you to focus your development environments on creating your models.

In order to do this, you need to write out the image, and specify a log directory, that create a file writer for it, and then write the image.

Let's take MNIST dataset as our dataset. For visualizing one image:

```
# Reshape the image for the Summary API.
img = np.reshape(train_images[0], (-1, 28, 28, 1))

# Clear out any prior log data.
!rm -rf logs

# Sets up a log directory.
logdir = "logs/train_data/image"
# Creates a file writer for the log directory.
file_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer(logdir)

# Using the file writer, log the reshaped image.
with file_writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.image("Training data", img, step=0)

%tensorboard --logdir logs/train_data
```

For another useful example, you may create a LambdaCallback and in each epoch create some images useful for interpreting the model behavior, such as computing confusion matrix and save it like the above mentioned code, and then see them in Images tab in TensorBoard.

Reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/image_summaries